# Haskell PostgreSQL Simple FromField

Tags: postgresql, haskell, field, instance, postgresql-simple

I'm having trouble with defining FromField instance for my custom enum data type:

```
data Role = Staff | Student deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

To represent `Role` in my database, I will use ints 0 and 1 (more roles could be added later) most likely `smallint`.

`Review` is used in my other data type that represents a row in my db table:

```
data ReviewAssignment = ReviewAssignment
  { aID :: ID
  , reviewID :: ID
  , reviewerID :: ID
  , revieweeID :: ID
  , reviewerRole :: Role -- <-- right there
  , reviewFinished :: Bool
  , reviewPoints :: Float
  } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

This is my FromRow instance for ReviewAssignment:

```
instance FromRow ReviewAssignment where
  fromRow = ReviewAssignment <$> field <*> field <*> field <*> field <*> field <*> field <*> field
```

Now I'm just missing the following which I don't understand how to implement :

```
instance FromField Role where
  fromField = undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably to late but something like this should work (hopefully):

```
instance FromField Role where
  fromField f mdata =
    return role
    where role = case mdata of
      Just 0 -> Staff   
      _      -> Student
```

Answer (score 1):

`fromField` should take an integer (the smallint from your database) and return a Role value. I sugegst you implement it using pattern matching. You can read more about [fromField in the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-FromField.html). You can also take inspiration from [predefined fromField implementations](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.1.2/docs/src/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-FromField.html).

Comment: I have read the documentation, but I still don't understand it quite clearly so I'm asking here. I do understand the concept, but I don't know how to do it with FromField